# My android phone cannot recognize my camera

Tags: camera, front-camera

How come my android phone cannot open my camera?

[image]

I do have the system app on my phone, but I find it in the `Apps` portion and no matter what kind of camera app or camera repair app, it will not work. One app asked if the camera was in use.

[image]

I cannot press the `lock` button with the `volume down` because my volume down button is stuck and broken. I tried downloaded the camera repair apps like `Camera (CMMFix) for Cyanogenmod` and it doesn't work. My phone was just fresh from factory reset.

Also I get random crashes like `camera and imageview` has stopped working randomly.

Comment: Did you install a custom rom?

Comment: I have no idea it's been passed on to many people I just revived it recently. It's been factory reset though I think that should wipe it out?

Comment: Check in settings > About phone

Comment: @TheOnlyAnil I just see a `custom build version` with numbers

Comment: Please do this step. Clear cache and data from settings, by clicking Camera starter as shown in second image